# JMX scrape failed

Tags: java, openshift, prometheus, jmx, scrape

I have a springboot application running on a pod in an openshift platform, and I have enabled application monitoring through prometheus (by creating a ServiceMonitor object). It works as expected, but sometimes this exception raises:

> JMX scrape failed: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: getMBeanInfo threw RuntimeException
> Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Has anyone run into the same issue?
Thanks in advance.